# jQuery - prop("checked") - All checkboxes or only those "checked"

Tags: jquery

Considering the following jQuery. Will the code locate a child element (of `$this`) that contains a *checkbox*, regardless of *check* or *not checked*, or only a *checkbox* that is `checked`?

```
$this.find('input').prop("checked")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither, it will find all `input` elements which are descendants of `$this` and return the `checked` property of the first one.

```
$this              // from "this" current element
  .find("input")   // find all "input" elements
  .prop("checked") // and return property of first one
```

If you want to match all checked checkboxes, do this instead:

```
$this.find(":checkbox:checked");
// or
$this.find("input[type=\"checkbox\"]").filter(":checked");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was certainly misunderstanding the code.

Comment: This may sounds stupid .. but I am assuming it will only return the checked property of an element that has a checked property? Meaning it will skip to the first element that has a checked property, rather than going to the first element and returning a null if the element does not contain a checked element.

Comment: I do not think it will skip, but you could try it out at jsfiddle.net